# How can I animate updating value on the website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I have an element, say `<p></p>` , which is live-updating number.

The thing is that I need to animate this number in a way similiar to this one: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/juergengenser/pen/VjEXgO) - but I have no idea how I should do it. 
I don't have scope of numbers - they are calculated based on API response and put into my 
`<p></p>`.

Anyone has any ideas/did something like this before?

Comment: does only that animation work for you. You can also try http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I'm not quite sure how should I implement it. Should I just wrap function responsible for calculating and add .fadeIn() to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two elements,in which we will set the new value alternatively & can have animation among these two. So it will look like a continuous chain of values.

**A Sample code:**

```js
var i=0;
function changeValue(){
  var newValue=Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  document.getElementById('item'+i).innerHTML=newValue;
  if(i==0)
    i=1;
  else
    i=0;
}
setInterval(changeValue,2000);
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:800';
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 44px;
}
#loader span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
          transform: translateY(100%);
  -webkit-animation: count 4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) infinite;
          animation: count 4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) infinite;
}
#loader span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
}
#loader span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes count {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
            transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
@keyframes count {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
            transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <span id='item0'></span>
  <span id='item1'></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example here:

```js
$('p').html("This is new text").hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a repeated fade-in / fade-out, you can simply use a single CSS `@keyframes` animation.

**Working example:**

```js
var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var value = 0;
var maxValue = 12; // <= this is your calculation from your API response
paragraph.classList.add('animate-value');

function incrementValue() {
    value++;
    paragraph.textContent = value;
    
    if (value === maxValue) {
        paragraph.classList.remove('animate-value');
        clearInterval(animateValue);
    }
}

var animateValue = setInterval(function(){incrementValue();}, 1500);
```

```css
div, p {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0;
font-size: 140px;
line-height: 200px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}

.animate-value {
animation: animateValue 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.show-value {
opacity: 100;
}

@keyframes animateValue {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
   25% {opacity: 100;}
   50% {opacity: 100;}
   75% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or what about a script, that moves the old elems to the top, then adds a new one at the bottom?:

```
var words=[];
var el={style:{}};
window.onload=function(){
   setInterval(function(){
        //add new values to old elem
       el.style.top="0px";
       var word=words.unshift();
      if(word){
          document.body.appendChild(el=document.createElement("p"));
          //new elems values
          el.style.top="100px";
          el.innerHTML=word;
      }
  },2000);
};
```

Then do the following css( to make it smooth):

```
p{transition:all ease 2s;}
```

To add new words, do this:

```
words.push("1");
```